# How to redirect a 404 error to the homepage using a link and not a path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, heroku, http-status-code-404, redirect

I want my website to redirect to the **homepage** when I get error 404. I am using this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

It works when the error is in the **root**, eg when  I type `www.example.com/skdsjdksjdjksdsdsd`

but when the error is under another path (not in the root) eg I type `www.example.com/sdasd/sdsdsdsdsdsag`

It does tries to redirect but I get an unstyled page with no javascript loaded.

Is that possible to replace index.php with my website url?

I am trying to redirect the error to a full url page like the code below but it doesn't work:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /https://www.mywebsite.com #doesn't work

 ErrorDocument 404 /www.mywebsite.com #doesn't work
```

Comment: You can perform an redirection to the full URL of your page.

Comment: okay that is what I am looking for, how can I do this ?

Comment: A URL does not have a leading slash... Why don't you simply take a look into the documentation? Each apache module has one, they are of really good quality and comes with clear examples. Start here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: Remove the leading **/** and you will be fine.

Comment: This question alone solved my problem! I have a React app with React Router that, when deployed in VestaCP, was getting 404 for any path besides the root if not accessed by a `<Link/>`. `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` did the trick for me.